# Have method run after child constructor's InitializeComponent is complete without implictly invoking in child classes

Tags: c#, winforms, design-patterns, aop

I'm not sure if this is possible or not, but what I would like to be able to do is to have all Children of a Parent base class to run a method defined in the base class without explicitly invoking it in the child class.

In other words, what I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       Setup(); // not run here if this instance is a child of parent
    }

    protected void Setup()
    {
        // code that depends on InitializeComponent being called in
        // both the parent and any Child's classes 
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
       //Setup(); is invoked here, without having to explicitly 
       // invoke in all children of Parent
    }
}
```

Is there a pattern that could enable this behaviour, or could perhaps Aspect Oriented Programming be a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could instead override the [`Form.OnLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx) method of the parent form; it's guaranteed to be called just before the Form is shown.

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    Setup();

    base.OnLoad(e);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you just want to override [`OnLoad`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.onload.aspx) method:

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent()
    {
       InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        // put initialization code here

        base.OnLoad(e);
    }
}
```

It is called when both parent and child components are initialized.
Don't forget to call `base.OnLoad` so that `Load` event handlers, if any, receive the event.

Answer (score 0):

The constructor of Child will automatically call the constructor of Parent (before its own code gets called, in fact), so in your situation above, Setup will always be called in the Child class (and InitializeComponent will be called twice).

Answer (score 0):

Running code in the `Load` event or `OnLoad` is often the worst solution.

If you want to run code once after the form load you can use `Shown` event, otherwise the form looks laggy and unresponsive you you have long running  code (controls are shown one after another).

If you really want to run code after the child constructor but before the load event, overriding OnHandleCreated is your best choice.

However: There is (at least) one thing left that won't work. I had a form base class that set a specific startup position / size regardless of what the child form defined. Every effort I made failed or the form was visible on the wrong location for a split second. This is how I solved it:

```
public class MyForm : Form
{
    private Size defaultSize;
    public MyForm()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.defaultSize = this.Size;
        this.fireOnBeforeLoad = true;
    }
    public new void ResumeLayout(bool performLayout)
    {
        base.ResumeLayout(performLayout);

        if (fireOnBeforeLoad)
        {
            fireOnBeforeLoad = false;
            OnBeforeLoad();
        }
    }
    protected virtual void OnBeforeLoad()
    {
        form.WindowState = FormWindowState.Normal;
        form.Size = defaultSize;
        form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
        var area = Screen.FromControl(form).WorkingArea;
        form.Size = defaultSize;
        form.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(
            (int)(area.Width - form.Width) / 2, 
            (int)(area.Height - form.Height) / 2);
    }
}
```

Here is the tricky part: After yo set the size, it somehow gets reverted on some point in the load process. The same thing happens if you call `Screen.FromControl(form)`. I suppose because `Screen.FromControl` eventually calls `Screen.FromHandle` and that will cause the handle to be created. But I suppose it does something else, too because if I run the above code in the `OnHandleCreated` method (after calling `base.OnHandleCreated` of course) it won't get the desired result. Because of this I set the size again after `Screen.FromControl` the last line is just to center the form on the screen.